# Does the regular value theorem applies to regular value whose level set is the empty set?

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

From a set of notes on smooth manifolds:
[image]

It says that even points that are not in the image of F are considered regular values. So the preimage of those points is just the empty set, but the regular value theorem does not make an exception for these points so that would be saying that the empty set is a submanifold with dimension M-N which would be false. So the regular value theorem should only be applied to points that are actually in the image of F correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, actually, the empty set *does* satisfy the definition of a submanifold.

Given a subset $S \subset M$ of a manifold $M$, the phrase "**$S$ is a submanifold of $M$ of dimension $k$**" is defined by a sentence that starts like this: *"for all $x \in S$ ..."*

In the case $S=\emptyset$, since the set $S$ has no points, any mathematical sentence that starts with *"for all $x \in S$..."* is [vacuously true](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth).

Comment: Hi, so this means the empty is a manifold for all dimensions then?

Comment: Yes, it's a manifold of every dimension (including 0, which is the dimension of a singleton as a manifold).